# How to write a file to Kafka Producer

Tags: file, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to load a simple text file instead of standard input in Kafka.
After downloading Kafka, I performed the following steps:

Started zookeeper:

> `bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties`

Started Server

> `bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`

Created a topic named "test":

> `bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test`

Ran the Producer:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test 
Test1
Test2
```

Listened by the Consumer:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --from-beginning
Test1
Test2
```

Instead of Standard input, I want to pass a data file or even a simple text file to the Producer which can be seen directly by the Consumer. Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can pipe it in:

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic my_topic
--new-producer < my_file.txt
```

Found [here](http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/157b71babg/kafka-producer-input-file).

From 0.9.0:

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic my_topic < my_file.txt
```

Comment: I am using Kafka-0.9. --new-producer is not supported in kafka-console-producer.sh, instead,

    $ kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic my_topic < my_file.txt

worked for me.

Comment: I think --new-producer is the actual producer from 0.9 :)

Comment: @BalázsMáriaNémeth, how to pass only n number of lines after fixed interval of time (for example pass first 10 lines, wait for 5 secs, pass 10-20 lines and so on). After end of all lines, it should start again from line 1?

Comment: You have to write you're own script I'm afraid. Python perhaps?

Comment: @vdep you should be able to do that using kafkacat: https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat

Comment: @FilipeCorreia, currently i am using shell script to do it. But `kafkacat`   does have more advanced features, i will give it a try.

Comment: How can I curl the data from this streaming website http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps ?

Comment: Has anybody tried with rotating `my_file.txt` ? say hourly rotating using `logrotate`

Comment: Really useful. Can it sustain multiple ~100Ko files sending? Would it be bad practice to do this?

Comment: This does not work for 0.11 .. any suggestions for the new version?

Comment: this is one time read right!, but how to read from a file incrementally?

Comment: This is producing data to a single partition instead of distributing to all assigned partitions. Any option to produce data to all partitions?

Comment: on Kafka 0.10 responds with "new-producer is not a recognized option"

Comment: Is there also a solution for windows cmd?

Answer (score 14):

```
$ kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic my_topic < my_file.txt
```

worked for me in Kafka-0.9.0

Answer (score 9):

Here are few ways which are little more generalised but may be overkill for simple file

**tail**

`tail -n0 -F my_file.txt | kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic my_topic`

*Explanation*

1. `tail` reads from the end of the file as it grows or logs are being added to it continuously
2. `-n0` indicates outputlast 0 lines so only new line is selected
3. `-F` follows the file by name instead the descriptor, hence it works even if it is rotated

**syslog-ng**

```
options {                                                                                                                             
    flush_lines (0);                                                                                                                
    time_reopen (10);                                                                                                               
    log_fifo_size (1000);                                                                                                          
    long_hostnames (off);                                                                                                           
    use_dns (no);                                                                                                                   
    use_fqdn (no);                                                                                                                  
    create_dirs (no);                                                                                                               
    keep_hostname (no);                                                                                                             
};

source s_file {
    file("path to my-file.txt" flags(no-parse));
}


destination loghost {
    tcp("*.*.*.*" port(5140));
}
```

*consuming*

`nc -k -l 5140 | kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic my_topic`

*Explanation(from `man nc`)*

```
-k' Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its current connection is completed. It is an error to use this option without the -l option.

-l' Used to specify that nc should listen for an incoming connection rather than initiate a connection to a remote host. It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -p, -s, or -z options. Additionally, any timeouts specified with the -w option are ignored.
```

*Ref*

[Syslog-ng](https://syslog-ng.org/)

Comment: Yes! this is great: UNIX way!

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "Hello" | kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic my_topic
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Sometimes the code is the documentation.  It's clearly just piping in some text.