# How to use a growing file as Apache Kafka producer and read only the newly appended data

Tags: apache-kafka, real-time, flume

I am trying to use file as my kafka producer. The source file grows continuously (say 20 records/lines per second). Below is a post similar to my problem:

[How to write a file to Kafka Producer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273587/how-to-write-a-file-to-kafka-producer)

But in this case, the whole file is read and added to the Kafka topic every time a new line is inserted into the file. I want only the newly appended lines to be sent to the topic (ie. if the file holds 10 lines already and 4 more lines are appended to it, only those 4 lines need to be sent to the topic).

Is there a way to achieve this ??

**Other solutions tried:**

1. Apache flume by using *source type* as 'spooldir'. But it was of no use since it reads data from new files that are added to the directory and not when data is appended to an already-read file.
2. Also we tried with flume *source type* as 'exec' and *command* as 'tail –F /path/file-name'. This too doesn't seem to work.

Suggestions for using any other tool is also welcomed as **my objective is to read the data from the file in real time** (ie. I need the data as soon as it is inserted into the file).

Comment: Did you try [FileSource Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-filestream/filestream_connector.html) from Kafka Connect?

Comment: Thanks Chin Huang. I wasn't aware of the connector. It worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options that you could look at, depending on your exact needs.

**Kafka Connect**

As stated by [Chin Huang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57719/chin-huang) above the [FileSource](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-filestream/filestream_connector.html#filesource-connector) Connector from Kafka Connect should be able to do what you want without installing additional software. Check out the [Connect Quickstart](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/quickstart.html) for guidance on how to get this up and running, they actually have an example for reading a file into Kafka.

**Logstash**

Logstash is the classic option for something like this, with its [Kafka](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-kafka.html) output it will do just what you want it to do, for one or muliple files. The following configuration should give you roughly what you want.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/path/to/your/file"
  }
output {
    kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "127.0.0.1:9092"
        topic_id => "topicname"
    }
}
```

**Filebeat**

[Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/kafka-output.html) is pretty similar to Logstash, it just offers less functionality if you want to perform additional processing on data read from the file. Also, it is written in go instead of java, so the footprint on the machine its running on should be smaller.
The following should be a minimal config to get you started (from memory, you might need to add a parameter or two if they are mandatory):

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /path/to/your/file

output.kafka:
  hosts: ["127.0.0.1:9092"]
  topic: 'topicname'
```

**Flume**

If you want to revisit your Flume option, have a look at the TaildirSource, I have not used it, but it sounds like it should fit your use case quite nicely.

Comment: All the solutions suggested worked for me :) Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Can we use the Kafka SpoolDir connector for this? I want to read only the updated/new records but from multiple files in a specific directory.