# Push files to Kafka Programaticaaly

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I want to push multiple json files (around 200k files) to kafka topic for testing purpose. I want to push each file as a message to kafka topic. What is the approach ?

Comment: [How to write a file to Kafka Producer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273587/how-to-write-a-file-to-kafka-producer)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt The thread you mentioned is to use command line and that too for single file. I want it for pushing around 200k files from a directory programatically

Comment: Where did you write requirement that in your question? Right now it says "I want to push whole file as **a** message". Also, please show the code that you have written as a [mcve] and indicate where the problem is.

Comment: Sorry @ErwinBolwidt its my mistake. Edited the question now.

Comment: Ideally, you push JSON objects from the file as individual messages. Don't attempt to push whole files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Kafka Connect with the [kafka-connect-spooldir](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir) connector. You can see it in action [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-in-action-enriching-csv-events-with-data-from-rdbms-into-AWS/).