# How to generate input data and stored it in to a local file and How we can read the data of this input generated file by using kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

For this i started Zookeeper:
`bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties`

then the kafka server:
`bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`

topic:
`bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic fast-messages`

then what is the next step for file generation ?

Comment: You can use language specific file generation code and then write a kafka producer which will read from file and write it to `fast-messages`.

Comment: Ok Thanks @Mukesh Prajapati

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *parse* the file, and write a Kafka producer from it.

Or you can just pipe the file directly into the Console Producer.

[How to write a file to Kafka Producer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273587/how-to-write-a-file-to-kafka-producer)

Or [use KafkaConnect FileSourceConnector](http://bigdatums.net/2017/06/20/writing-file-content-to-kafka-topic/)

Comment: Thanks, using above link i got the result.

Answer (score 1):

For this same Question i also referred another link and i got the result. The Link is --> https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/quickstart.html

Followings are the step that i followed-->

Step 1: Start Zookeeper 
`bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties`

Step 2: Start kafka server 
`bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`

Step 3: create a topic named as "fast-messages" 
`bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic fast-messages`

step 4: Run Producer 
`kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic fast-messages --new-producer < my_file.txt`

step 5: Listened by the Consumer:

`/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic fast-messages --from-beginning`